# Efficient algorithm to list all sequences that sum up to a constant value

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

We are given

1. A set of T numbers S1, S2,....ST
2. An integer called Range

This means 1st number can take on (2*Range+1) values (S1-Range,S1-Range+1,...S1, S1+1,....S1+Range) Similarly 2nd, ...Tth can take on 2*Range+1 values

I.e we have (2*Range-1)^T possible sequences (S1-Range,S2,...ST), (S1-Range+1,S2,...ST), ....., (S1, S2-Range,S3,....ST) etc

Question: How to efficiently find the set of sequences whose sum is S1+S2+...+ST?

Brute Force approach approach is to loop through all possible sequences, check sum and only print sequences whose sum satisfies the test.  But this takes exponential time and I am looking to see if there is a well known algorithm to list this more efficiently.

Comment: Let $R=$ Range. Why did you switch from $(2R + 1)$ possible values for each summand to $(2R-1)^T$ possible sequences?  Shouldn't this be $(2R+1)^T$?

Comment: What do you mean by "efficiently"? Assume that $T$ is even and Range is 1. Then all sequences in which $\frac{T}{2}$ of the numbers are set to $S_i - 1$ and the other half is set to $S_i + 1$ are part of the set you are looking for. There are $\frac{T!}{2 \cdot \left(\frac{T}{2}\right)!} \in \mathcal{O}(2^{\frac{T}{2}})$ such sequences. Thus, you will always have an exponential number of solutions.